# Prevent LazyVStack contents from going behind transparent Pinned Section Header

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a pinned Section header in a LazyVstack.
I want the section header background to be transparent.
The issue i am facing is that the content of LazyVstack scrolls through behind the section and the transparent section and content gets mixed up.

I want to do something like masking the section so that anything which goes behind section gets clipped.

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {

                Section(header:
                    Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .zIndex(-1) // zIndex here
                ) {
                    
                    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                        
                        Section (header:
                                    Text("Header")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            // give background here
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(.clear)
                        ) {
                            ForEach(0..<30) { item in
                                Text("Item \(item)")
                            }
                        }

                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.never)
        .font(.title2)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: "so that anything which goes behind section gets clipped" that is the opposite of "transparent" isn't it?

Comment: suppose that red rectangle in background is  an image

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want a transparent section header or not? The question is contradictory here.

Comment: all i need is to prevent the contents of LazyVStack going behind the header when the header is pinned. I have already made the header background transparent.

Comment: If you want to "prevent the contents of LazyVStack going behind the header", then the background should ***not*** be transparent, should it?

Comment: if it should not be transparent, then how can i see the image view behind it? 
Could you please look at the image i have uploaded. You'll get what i mean

Comment: The example is artificial. You have .zIndex(-1), which makes the red rectangle be below the stack contents. If you remove that line, the contents will scroll "below" the red rectangle, which is probably exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I will edit and upload the images ike what i want and what issue i am facing

Comment: I have updated the question with detailed images mate

Comment: Just set a background Color to your section header rectangle.

Comment: i have already said the rectangle could be sometimes an Image